# What is the Windows equivalent of "pidof" from Linux?

Tags: c, windows, batch-file

In a batchscript, I need to get a list of process IDs with given binary path `C:\path\to\binary.exe`.
In Linux, I can just do `pidof /path/to/binary`.

Is there a Win32 executable which does the same, supported from WinXP Home to Win7 (tasklist won't work)?

The package which includes this has to be portable, so a 10MB download is not what I'm looking for.

Is there a C function available which does this *and* is supported from WinXP to Win7? Note: I want to match a process path, not a filename which could be used by other applications too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Toolhelp APIs to enumerate processes, get their full path and compare it with the required process name. You need to walk the modules list for each process. The first module in the list is the process executable itself. Here's a sample code:

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{

    if( argc > 1 )
    {
        printf( "\nGetting PID of: %s\n", argv[1] );
        HANDLE hProcSnapshot = ::CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0 );
        if( INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hProcSnapshot )
        {
            PROCESSENTRY32 procEntry = {0};
            procEntry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
            if( ::Process32First( hProcSnapshot, &procEntry ) )
            {
                do
                {
                    HANDLE hModSnapshot = ::CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, procEntry.th32ProcessID );
                    if( INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hModSnapshot )
                    {
                        MODULEENTRY32 modEntry = {0};
                        modEntry.dwSize = sizeof( MODULEENTRY32 );
                        if( Module32First( hModSnapshot, &modEntry ) )
                        {
                            if( 0 == stricmp( argv[1], modEntry.szExePath ) )
                            {
                                printf( "\nPID: %ld\n", procEntry.th32ProcessID );
                                ::CloseHandle( hModSnapshot );
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        ::CloseHandle( hModSnapshot );
                    }
                }
                while( ::Process32Next( hProcSnapshot, &procEntry ) );
            }
            ::CloseHandle( hProcSnapshot );
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need. I've seen `::` more times, is that a C++ thing? Now I'll try to get it work with Unicode names, like Chinese.

Comment: With a small modification, it works for [all processes](http://forum.sysinternals.com/listing-processes-and-finding-executable_topic6595_post26001.html#26001). It also works now for special characters, like Chinese. For that to work, the system had to be Chinese, otherwise it would show a `?`.

Answer (score 5):

wmic.exe is available on XP, Vista and 7 and can do this. However, it does not come with Windows XP Home edition.

```
wmic process where ExecutablePath='C:\\windows\\system32\\notepad.exe' get ProcessId
```

If you want support for Windows XP Home too, you can use [EnumProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682629%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [GetModuleFileNameEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683198%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). The downside here is that you won't be able to query names of processes running by another user if you're not running as administrator. [QueryFullProcessImageName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684919%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) will probably do the trick here, but it's Vista+.

If that's not enough, you'll need [Process32First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684834%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (swatkat's code). For each process you need to call [Module32First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684218%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and then get `MODULEENTRY32->szExePath`. Note that even this is not completely portable and will not work well on x64 where you'll need [QueryFullProcessImageName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684919%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell can solve your problems, if is buit in in Win 7, and downloadable on the other OSs.

```
param($fileName)
Get-Process | where -FilterScript {$_.MainModule.FileName -eq $fileName}
```

This script will receive one parameter, the filename you are looking for, and it will output the filename of its executable.

You can call this from a bat file by doing:

powershell -Command "& {Get-Process | where -FilterScript {$_.MainModule.FileName -eq %FILENAME%}"

Comment: I would like to have it portable, without installing dozens of things. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: Fair enough. Keep in mind that Powershell is only one thing and the download is 5MB for Windows Vista and 1.6MB for Windows XP. It is also built in into win 7. Source: http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/download.mspx

Comment: Isn't this exactly backwards from what the OP asked?  He wants to know which pids are open on a given executable, not which executable is open on a given pid.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a small C# application which first calls [Process.GetProcessesByName(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9.aspx) , then go over the results and print the [Id](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.id.aspx) property of each one when the MainModule.[FileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processmodule.filename.aspx) is equal to the path you are looking for.

Comment: That returns only a process name like GetModuleFileName or CreateToolhelp32Snapshot. Is there a function which works from WinXP to Win7 and returns a path?

Comment: @Lekensteyn - you are right, I edited the answer for the path retreiving.

Answer (score 0):

I use `pidof` with process name as the parameter. I haven't needed the executable path before. I use it like:

```
pidof php
```

And it just returns the PID of the running process. Similarly with PowerShell, I can use it as follows:

```
(get-process php).id
```

And it returns the PID as `pidof` does.